# Open Item Detail Page in Edit Mode Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, onclick, modal-dialog

I am attempting to open a New item Page inside a button click event.
I have a `ListView` with an **Add** button. If user is not logged in, a login screen will appear. After User is authenticated and clicks OK, I want to open the Add New Item detail page. But it keeps showing the Item `ListView` Page.

TLDR;
This is not working:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new ItemEditorPage()));
```

My code:

```
//Add a new Item.
async void AddItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure they're logged in before adding.
    // Checks if User is authenticated. Displays Login Page if not 
    //Logged in.
    if (await Utility.EnsureLoggedIn(this, true))
    {
    //If user is already logged in, show New Idea Page
    //Works so Far
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new 
        ItemEditorPage(/* null creates a new Idea */)));
    }
}
//If not Logged In Log in screen appears
//Login Click Event.
private async void BtnLogin_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (loginSuccessful)
    {
        await DisplayAlert(Strings.AlertTitle_Info, "Login 
        successful.", Strings.Button_OK);
        //Removes Login Modal(**This Works**)
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        //Calling Same Code as above after authenticated
        if (await Utility.EnsureLoggedIn(this, true))
        {
            //**NOT WORKING** Returns to Item Listview. Not the Add New Item 
        //Detail View
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new
            NavigationPage(new ItemEditorPage()));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged it to check that EnsureLoggedIn() is working properly?

Comment: @Jason Yes. Logged in = true.